# Proof that a certain relation is an equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a ring $R$, call $S$ the set of pairs $(K,f)$, with $K$ a field and $f:R\to K$ a ring homomorphism. Consider the following relation on $S$: $(K,f)\sim (K',f')$ iff exists a pair $(L,g)$ in $S$ such that $K,K'\subseteq L$, and, for any $r\in R$, $f(r)=f'(r)=g(r)$ in $L$. The fact that $\sim$ is symmetric and reflexive is trivial, however I don't know how to prove that the relation is transitive. Can you help me? Thanks

Ps: it seems to me that proving the transitivity of $\sim$ is equivalent to proving that if two fields $K,K'$ both contain a copy of another field $H$, then exists a field $L$ containing $K,K'$, such that $H\hookrightarrow K\hookrightarrow L$ and $H\hookrightarrow K\hookrightarrow L$ are the same homomorphism from $H$ to $L$. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631028.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in proving that what I stated in the p.s. is true, because this is an exercise that our professor left us after a review about tensor products and residue fields (using these constructions I should be able to prove the transitivity proving the equivalent condition of the p.s.)

Comment: To prove transitivity, suppose you have that $R\to K$ is equivalent to $R\to L$, and that $R\to L$ is equivalent to $R\to M$. By definition this means that there are maps $K,L\to F$ which equalize the map from $R$, and maps $L,M\to F'$ which equalize the map from $R$. Consider $F\otimes_L F'$, this is a non-zero ring and so has a maximal ideal, and quotienting yields a field $F''$ and a map $F\otimes_L F'\to F''$. We then naturally get maps $K\to F\to F\otimes_L F'\to F''$ and $M\to F'\to F\otimes_L F'\to F''$. To see that these equalize $R$ is simple since their restrictions to $R$

Comment: agree with the maps $R\to L\to F\to F\otimes_L F'\to F''$ and $R\to L\to F'\to F\otimes_L F'\to F''$ which are equal by the definition of the tensor product

Comment: I'm a bit confused, did you mean to take the tensor product $F\otimes_R F'$?

Comment: @Dorian I mean what I said, I'm pretty sure. It shouldn't matter much though, right?

Comment: @AlexYoucis that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?