# Question about tensor product of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Take two ring homomorphism, $a:R\to A$ and $ b:R\to B$. In general, there is not a field $F$ such that $A,B\hookrightarrow F$, and such that $R\to A \hookrightarrow F$ and $R\to B \hookrightarrow F$ are the same (as ring homomorphisms). However I don't understand why such a field doesn't always exist: if I consider the tensor product of algebras $A\otimes_RB$, and take its quotient by a maximal ideal, isn't the result a field containing a copy of $A$ and $B$, with the inclusions equalizing $a$ and $b$? Thanks for any clarify

Comment: $A\otimes_R B$ may be zero. For instance, if $R=\Bbb Z$, $A=\Bbb Q$, and $B=\Bbb Z/2$.

Comment: @KReiser thank you; when $A$ and $ B$ are fields too, however, it can't happen that their tensor product is zero right?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are fields in that example.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are $R$-free, then it cannot happen unless $A = B  = 0$. Proof: tensoring commutes with direct sums, hence is $A \simeq R^{(I)}, B \simeq R^{(J)}$ we have $A \otimes_R B \simeq R^{(I \times J)}$. This is nonzero for non-empty $I \times J$. In particular this is the situation when $R$ is a field.

Comment: @KReiser sorry you're right. However I don't understand why, when answering this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4288719/682140), in the comments, Alex Youcis said that $F\otimes_LF'$ is a nonzero ring

Comment: qualcuno has answered, both above and below: if $A$ and $B$ are free and nonzero over $R$, like when $R$ is a field and $A,B$ are nontrivial vector spaces, then it cannot be the case that $A\otimes_R B$ is zero. You ought to be able to check this with the definition of the tensor product of vector spaces, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the inclusions $A \to A \otimes_R B$ and $B \to A \otimes_R B$ need not be injective. Hence $A$ and $B$ are not included in $A \otimes_R B$, let alone a quotient of the former by a maximal ideal.

Under the identification $A \simeq A \otimes_R R$, the inclusion $A \to A \otimes_R B$ can be viewed as $1_A \otimes i$ where $i \colon R \to B$ is the $R$-lineal map $1 \mapsto 1$. In general $A \otimes_R -$ does not preserve monomorphisms. A sufficient condition would be for $A$ to be $R$-flat (in which case $A \otimes_R -$ preserves all monos. It is also worth recalling that projectives and in particular free modules are flat). Even then, we may lose injectivity when dividing by the aforementioned maximal ideal.

Your question can be rephrased as "when are there inclusions $A, B \to D$ to a domain $D$". This is because a field is a domain, and having the result for domains implies the result for field by composing with the injection $D \to \mathsf{Frac}(D)$. Note that as a necessary condition both $A$ and $B$ should be domains.

In the question you cite in the comments, the tensor product that is claimed to be non-zero is taken over a field $L$. Hence the discussion in the comments of this answer applies: if $L$ is a field and $A$ and $B$ are non-trivial $L$-vector spaces so is $A \otimes_L B$.